# Scratch card effect for ios

Tags: ios, scratchcard

I am trying to make a scratch card type of application for iOS.
I am able to wipe the image using a finger initially.
But I want to come to prompt an alert as soon as the image is completely wiped out.

I used the following code to wipe:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    mouseSwiped = NO;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    mouseSwiped = YES;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);

    [self.tempDrawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);

    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);

    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);

    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), brush );

    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red, green, blue, 1.0);

    CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),kCGBlendModeNormal);



    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());

    self.tempDrawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    [self.tempDrawImage setAlpha:opacity];

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();



    lastPoint = currentPoint;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);


}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    if(!mouseSwiped) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
        [self.tempDrawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
        CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), brush);
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red, green, blue, opacity);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        CGContextFlush(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        self.tempDrawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.mainImage.frame.size);
    [self.mainImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];
    [self.tempDrawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:opacity];
    self.mainImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    pixelImage=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    self.tempDrawImage.image = nil;
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698930/how-image-pixel-data-scans-the-image-pixels on `touchesEnded` you calculate the non transparent pixel, if it exist your image is not clear, else clear.

Comment: thanx for the reply... but the code does not work... for what i am looking for

Answer (score 0):

You get idea from third party [ios-scratch-n-see](https://github.com/moqod/ios-scratch-n-see) library.

This is an Objective-C class that helps create a masking effect similar to a scratch card, when swiping on the screen the user can see an image being revealed as he swipes. This is a cool effect that can be applied for a scratch card action or wiping a glass.

Comment: this wiping effect has already been done. but the next part for prompting alert is still not there.